# Indexing folders: Not detecting a directory

Tags: php, file, glob, readdir, scandir

```
<?php
$dir = '';

if(isset($_GET['dir']) && !empty($_GET['dir']) && !stristr($_GET['dir'], '.')){
    $dir = '/'. $_GET['dir'];
    echo '<a href="files.php">back to /</a><br><br>';
}

foreach(scandir('files'. $dir) as $filename){
    if($filename == ".." || $filename == "."){
        // do nothing. We want files and folders, not dots.
    }
    else
    {   
        if(is_file($filename)){
            echo '<a href="files/'. $filename .'">'. $filename .'</a><br>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a href="files.php?path='. $filename .'">'. $filename .' (dir)</a><br>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

So I want to make a file indexer for my site, just like you would see in windows explorer (NOT ie!). But the script I currently have just detects the one folder in the `files/` directory (were all the files are that I want to index) and completely misses the files, in or outside of the sub-folder. And when I click on the sub folder, it keeps acting like its in the main folder (`files/`).

How do I solve this?

Another question, should I use `glob` or `scandir`? It's only going to contain ~80 files so I won't have to deal with the memory_limit problem like it notes on the [PHP.net page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php):

> Don't use glob() if you try to list files in a directory where very much files are stored (>100.000). You get an "Allowed memory size of XYZ bytes exhausted ..." error.
>   You may try to increase the memory_limit variable in php.ini. Mine has 128MB set and the script will still reach this limit while glob()ing over 500.000 files.

---

Updated code after Barmar's solution:

```
<?php
            $dir = '';

            if(isset($_GET['dir']) && !empty($_GET['dir']) && !stristr($_GET['dir'], '.')){
                $dir = $_GET['dir'];
                echo '<a href="files.php">Back to /</a><br><br>';
            }

            foreach(scandir('files'. $dir) as $filename){
                if($filename == ".." || $filename == "."){
                    // do nothing. We want files and folders, not dots.
                }
                else
                {   
                    if(is_file($dir .'/'. $filename)){
                        echo '<a href="'. $filename .'">'. $filename .'</a><br>';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo '<a href="files.php?dir='. $dir .'/'. $filename .'">'. $filename .' (dir)</a><br>';
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: You might want better control of this. Check out: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: To fix the other issue (staying in the same path) change ?path= to ?dir=

Comment: @RobW I've checked it out, but that seems way harder then this needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scandir` returns filenames, not pathnames, so you need to add the directory prefix:

```
foreach(scandir('files'. $dir) as $filename){
    if($filename == ".." || $filename == "."){
        // do nothing. We want files and folders, not dots.
    }
    else
    {   
        if(is_file($filename)){
            echo '<a href="files/'. $dir . '/' . $filename .'">'. $filename .'</a><br>';
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<a href="files.php?dir=' . $dir . '/' . $filename .'">'. $filename .' (dir)</a><br>';
        }
    }
}
```

You were also missing `files.php?` in the first link, and the second link should use `dir=` to make it recurse into the subdirectory.

Comment: I had `files.php?` there cause that would be a direct link to the files inside that directory. Now I've corrected that, and it detects the dummy file that I've put in `files/folder1/` but it reads it as a folder. So it lists `files/folder1/` as a folder, `files/dummy.txt` as a folder, and when I go into `files/folder1/` it detects `files/folder1/dummy.txt` also as a folder. (See updated question with my current code)

Comment: You still need the directory prefix in the direct link to the files. I've updated my answer for that case.

Comment: I found the problem. We forgot to change the paths in the `is_file` function aswell. 'Guess we're all humans.